# Filter available staff after a specific date taken from a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm attempting to set up a filter in cell U3 that will extract the staff from the left hand table that are available after a specfic date specified in cell S2. For clarity, each member of staff is assigned to different projects with a start and end date - this is why they have multiple entries in the table.

I have created the following filter in cell U3 with the aim of extracting the available staff after the date 01/11/2022 as denoted in cell S2 (please see image) `=FILTER(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date]>$S$2), {1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0})`

[image: Table of data and Filter to extract available staff]

As you can see, the result of the filter is showing me the 3 people still allocated to a project after the 01/11/22, whereas my hope is to have the following list :

**Employee**   **End Date**

Peter            30/06/2022

Richard          30/09/2020

Chris            31/05/2021

Roger            30/09/2022

Wesley           31/08/2021

Any ideas on what I'd need to change to extract the above data would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

`=LET(uniqueEmployees,UNIQUE(data[Employee]), maxDatePerEmployee,BYROW(uniqueEmployees,LAMBDA(e,MAX(FILTER(data[End Date],data[Employee]=e)))), EmployeesWithMaxDate,CHOOSE({1,2},uniqueEmployees,maxDatePerEmployee), FILTER(EmployeesWithMaxDate,maxDatePerEmployee<=E1))`

- `uniqueEmployees` returns a list of unqiue names
- `maxDatePerEmployee` returns per unique employee the latest date
- using `choose` we build the new matrix
- which then gets filtered by the available date - all employees whose latest end date is before the available date are returned.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ike, works great for getting the names, is there anything else I need to do for it to copy across the end dates in to the new table too?

One thing I should have included too which I hid as I didn't think it was necessary to explain my problem but may well cause another problem is that I'd like to copy across to the new table the employees associated discipline, which in my original data is in the hidden column B, e.g. engineer, QA, etc

Comment: I reduced the columns for my example  - you still can your table.

Comment: I have the date showing now, school boy error on my part. The bit I'm unsure on is how to get it to show the additional column for role and how to output that in to the new filter so it shows, employee, role, end date.

Comment: you can use your table AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl as shown in your question - and then, at the end, use the same outer FILTER as in your own example

Comment: When I try that unfortunately I receive an error - 

=FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl,LET(uniqueEmployees,UNIQUE(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]), maxDatePerEmployee,BYROW(uniqueEmployees,LAMBDA(e,MAX(FILTER(AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[End Date],AllStaffProjectAllocationTbl[Employee]=e)))), EmployeesWithMaxDate,CHOOSE({1,2},uniqueEmployees,maxDatePerEmployee), FILTER(EmployeesWithMaxDate,maxDatePerEmployee<=S2)),{1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0})


Where the 1's at the end are for the employee, role and end date columns I wish to extract. Any idea where I've gone wrong?